# LWC Submit for approval action in apex method

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, aura

I have basically a simple custom made button that needs to auto submit the account for approval like standard functionality button but with specific comments added.

```
import { LightningElement, track, api, wire } from 'lwc';
import { getRecord, getFieldValue } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import { updateRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';

import startApproval from '@salesforce/apex/LWCSubmitForApproval.approvalInit';
import getApprovalComments from '@salesforce/apex/LWCSubmitForApproval.getApprovalComments';

export default class lwcSubmitForApproval extends LightningElement {

    @track startApproval;
    @track disabled = false;
    @track error;

    @api recordId; // Account Id

    @wire(getApprovalComments, { accId: '$recordId' })
    approvalCommentsWired;

    get approvalComments(){
        return this.approvalCommentsWired && this.approvalCommentsWired.data;
    }

    // onclick button handler
    submitForApproval() {
        console.log(this.approvalCommentsWired.data);
        startApproval({ accId: this.recordId, comment: this.approvalCommentsWired.data }).then(result =>{
            console.log(result);
            if(result){
                this.showToast("Success");
                this.showSpinner = false;
            }
            this.showSpinner = false;
        }).catch(error => {
            this.showToast("Error");
            console.log(error);
            this.error = error;
            this.showSpinner = false;
        })

    }
}
```

+++ apex class

```
/**
 * Created by 13ent on 8/13/2020.
 */

public with sharing class LWCSubmitForApproval {

    /**
    ** This method initiates an approval process for the given object
    */
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=false)
    public static void approvalInit(String accId, String comment){
        Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest req = new Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest();
        req.setComments(comment);
        req.setObjectId(accId);
        Approval.ProcessResult result;
        try{
            // submit the approval request for processing
            result = Approval.process(req);
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.debug('No approval process has been setup yet.');
        }
    }
}
```

I am not getting any response from clicking the button calling the submitForApproval() method.  Any idea why?  How to call my apex class so that it works?

Answer (score 3):

Your method returns `void` (no value), *and* you're swallowing errors (never do this!). You should throw a new exception to invoke the error handler if you have an error:

```
}catch(Exception e){
    throw new AuraHandledException(e.getMessage());
}
```

This will allow you to detect if there's an error.

Note that if `then` is called, then there was no fatal exception. There's no need to check `if(result)` for a void return type, as there will never be a result.